# Displaying Gnuplot 3D-mesh cells value by placing the mouse cursor over it

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, 3d-model, gnuplot-iostream

I have been using Gnuplot to display 3D-mesh graphs (surface graphs) for a while. I am now striving to get Gnuplot 3D-mesh cell values displayed by placing the mouse cursor (pointer) over it. I have seen the cell fourth dimension (color intensity value) can get displayed. Could anybody help?

This is my GNUPLOT code

```
set cbrange [0.0:.2]
set palette defined (0 'white', 1 'midnight-blue')
set pm3d
set contour surface
set cntrparam levels incremental 0, 50, 1000
set xrange [0:1300]
set yrange [0:1500]
set zrange [0:1000]
set xyplane at 0
set view 9, 88, 2.3
set view equal xy

splot '-' using 1:2:3:4 notitle with lines lw .3 lc rgb 'black'
```

I appreciate your comments

Javero

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are looking for something like this? The points for hypertext anchor are made with pointsize 2 (for easy capture) and fully transparent, i.e. invisible (whatever) color `0xff......` (scheme `0xaarrggbb`).

Check `help hypertext`.

**Script:**

```
### show hypertext in 3D
reset session

# create some test data
set samples 16
set isosamples 16
set table $Data
    f(x,y)=(sin(1.3*x)*cos(.9*y)+cos(.8*x)*sin(1.9*y)+cos(y*.2*x))+3
    splot '++' u 1:2:(f($1,$2))
unset table

set palette defined (0 'white', 1 'midnight-blue')
set pm3d hidden noborder depthorder
set xyplane relative 0
set key noautotitle

splot $Data u 1:2:3 w pm3d, \
         '' u 1:2:3:(sprintf("%.2f",$3)) w labels hypertext \
            point pt 7 ps 2 lc rgb 0xff123456
### end of code
```

**Result:** (screen capture from wxt terminal)

[image]

Comment: Clever!  And yes, you could print the value of a 4th column instead of z.

Comment: @Ethan Well, thanks to the possibilities of gnuplot and those who are developing and maintaining it ;-). I couldn't find an easy way to create grid data _and_ add a 4th column for the test data via `splot ... w table`. Probably, I would have to use `set print` and a `do for` loop.

Comment: Thank you theozh. This is exactly what I am trying to do. However I now realize that i need to look into it to find out the specifics on using hypertext within "splot". I am actually coding a C++ program which displays a really large Gnuplot 3D surface.

Comment: @Javero The above example has only 16x16=256 points. I haven't tested how it would work with 100x100 or 1000x1000 datapoints. Not sure, whether it might get extremely slow or probably extremely memory intensive.